# What happens to the Stack and the sp when we write the PUSH command? (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86

I just started learning Assembly and my friend and I got different ideas about what exactly happens in the following command:

Push 1234h

Our problem is: where will the first digits (12) will go to in the stack ?
 ss:[sp-2]    ?
 ss:[sp-4]    ?

*sp =stack pointer

Comment: By the way, you could figure this out by yourself by writing `push 1234h / mov al,[sp]`, and then examine the value of `al`, then `mov al,[sp-1]` again.

Comment: Related: [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993) re: how `push 1234` assembles.  Most assemblers pick an operand-size that matches the mode they're assembling for. (e.g. 64 for `bits 64`)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about x86 hardware (since you specify the `sp` register), the bytes will be pushed highest-order (most significant) to lowest-order (least significant). In this case, it'll push the byte `12h`, followed by the byte `34h`. Since the x86 stack pointer decreases when you push items, the memory layout would look like this:

```
[sp+1] = 12h
[sp]   = 34h
```

If you access [sp] as a word (two bytes), you'll get your original value:

```
[sp] = 1234h
```

Comment: +1. And to directly answer the OP's question, the value 12h will be stored at [original_SP-1]

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not but both of you can be right. The bytes ordering depends on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your machine.

Comment: x86 is *always* little-endian, so there's only one possibility for endianness.  Also, the question is really whether the default operand-size is 16 or 32.  Both are possible depending on the current mode you're assembling for, and thus whether the assembler uses `push dword imm32` or `push word imm16` if you don't override the size.  [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993)

Answer (score 0):

In real mode (it looks like you're trying to make programs for it), address is calculated first. The formula is pretty simple:

```
address = (segment<<4)+offset
```

Then this address is substracted by size of element you're trying to push (`word`: 2 bytes, `dword`: 4 bytes, `qword`: 8 bytes).
Third step is writing data on resulting position. Therefore if `SS` is `0x30` and `SP` `0xFF`, then:

1. `address = (0x30<<4)+0xFF = 0x3FF`
2. Element is word, so we substract `2`: `position = 0x3FF - 2 = 0x3FD`
3. Writing data on resulting position (as C pointers): `*(unsigned char*)position = LOBYTE(0x1234)`, 
   `*((unsigned char*)position+1) = HIBYTE(0x1234)`.

So, `byte SS:[SP] = 0x34` and `byte SS:[SP+1] = 0x12`. Note that stack grows/expands down, so there won't be `SP-x`, but `SP+x`.

In protected mode, things are bit more complicated (I'll write here only process of working with segment register):

1. First, processor get's address of Global Descriptor Table Descriptor (which is loaded by `LGDT` instruction).
2. Processor compares value of segment register with size of GDT (if it's greater, exception is thrown). It also checks if segment register isn't pointing to null descriptor (`SS!=0`)
3. Then processor gets pointer to GDT entries, and calculates offset from start of GDT (using `SS*8`).
4. Processor must check some things:

   4.1. Is segment present?
   4.2. Do we have enough priviliges to access segment?
   4.3. Is it code segment?
   4.4. Is it writable?
   4.5. Is `ESP*granularity+base < limit`
   4.6. Is it system segment?
5. Then it calculates address by `base_of_segment+ESP`.
6. After it it continues similary to real mode.