# How do I print a blank space using x86 assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'm new to x86 assembly. 
My output currently looks like this:

```
1|*
2|** ...
8|********
9|*********
10|**********
11|***********
```

I want there to be a space in 1-9 so that it forms a straight line. Like this:

```
 9|
10|
11|
```

I don't know how to do it. I was thinking maybe using printChar (I want it in x86 assembly)

My code for printing the stars and lines:

```
beginLoop:   dec numItems
         push numItems
         call printInt //Prints 'numItems' number

         mov al,'|'
         push al
         call printChar //Prints bar line next to number  

  starLoop:    mov al, '*'
               push al
               call printChar //Prints a single star

         mov [numStars], 0 
         inc numStars  //numStars increases by 1
         mov ecx, [esi] //ebx knows inputted value 
         cmp [numStars], ecx //numStars must equal value inputted 
         jne starLoop

nextValue : call printNewLine
            add esi, 4 //Move to next number
            cmp[esi], [items]
            jne beginLoop
```

Comment: If you can output characters like `9`, `|`, `.` or `*`, you can output a space too. Just output an ASCII 32. What is the problem?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't do anything. I am using visual studio. I don't know whether that may be it.

Comment: My code was : { mov al,'|'
    push al
    call printChar }

Comment: Then show how you output, say, a `*`. You simply output a space the same way. Edit your question and show your relevant code.

Comment: `push al` is an invalid instruction. `mov al,'|'` is not referring to the space character. Use ASCII code 32 for that. Write `mov al, 32` or clearer `mov al, ' '`.

Comment: For the record, [MSVC assembles `push al` into a `push eax` instruction](https://godbolt.org/g/GMCcro).  This is pretty broken (and seems like a terrible design vs. being an assemble-time error), but happens to work for what the OP is doing.  I assume MASM behaves the same as MSVC inline asm for this.  (`push al` is not encodeable in machine-code.  The only possible operand-sizes are 32 and 16.  (Or 64 and 16 in 64-bit code.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec)

Comment: @PeterCordes See, I didn't know there are assemblers that allow `push al`. IMO that should never exist. I've always preferred (and still do) WYSIWYG.

Comment: Agreed.  I got curious because this user posted a question a day or so ago with the same invalid instruction and claimed it assembled, so I tested it.  Assembling `push al` is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code now will have something like this:

```
mov     eax, [number]
call    YourPrintRoutine
```

To introduce right-alignment on these numbers, you compare the number with 10, and only when the number is less than 10 do you first print a single space character.

```
    mov     eax, [number]
    push    eax
    cmp     eax, 10
    jnb     NotBelow10
    push    " "
    call    PrintChar
NotBelow10:
    call    PrintInt
```

---

### Are you sure this is the code that produces the above results?

- With `mov [numStars], 0` in the middle of your *starLoop* it's a miracle that it can display the right amount of stars!
- With `dec numItems` decrementing a value it's strange that you get an incrementing sequence of numbers on screen!

Comment: I have tried your solution and it still isn't working.

Comment: You have `mov eax, " "` *after* your `push eax`.  Surely you should just `push " "` if the function uses a stack-args calling convention.  (I don't think it's Irvine32 or whatever with args in eax)

Comment: Apparantly you push the argument for *printInt* instead of passing it in `EAX`. Secondly to display the spacecharacter, you don't use *printInt*, but a text print service.