# push a byte on stack (IA32)

Tags: assembly, x86

There is a question on my textbook:
Give the correct suffix based on the operands:

```
push $0xFF
```

And the answer is:

```
pushl $0xFF
```

But why not **`pushb $0xFF`**(I think `pushb` doesn't exist) or **`pushw $0xFF`** (`pushw` does exist), since `0xFF` is one byte, why it has to be 'l' which is 32 bits/4 bytes?

Comment: The size of the argument is not obvious from that question. So it technically could have been a 16-bit push as well (x86 supports this). Maybe they prefer 32-bit alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The *default* operand-size for `push` in AT&T syntax** (and in all other assemblers, like NASM and MASM) **is the width of the current mode**.  (16 bits in 16-bit mode, 32 bits in 32-bit mode, 64 bits in 64-bit mode.)  This matches the "stack width" of `call`/`ret`.

[How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushe-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-speci)

The default version of `pop` is also the version that takes no extra machine-code prefixes to encode.

Most instructions require an explicit operand-size when there's ambiguity, e.g. `mov $1234567, (%esp)` is invalid, but `mov %eax, (%esp)` is legal because a register implies the operand-size.

But `push`-immediate if funny: non-default widths for `push` are so rarely used that asm syntax designers chose to give it a default without requiring `pushl $0xff` (AT&T) or `push dword 0xff` (NASM).  Note that Intel-syntax came first; AT&T came after.  So perhaps the AT&T syntax designers were following the conventions of early Intel-syntax assemblers.

I point this out because it's only 1 extra letter for AT&T syntax for a size suffix, but more clunky looking in Intel syntax.

`push`-immediate was *heavily* used in traditional inefficient calling conventions that always pass args on the stack, so it makes sense to make it easy to type.

---

**Did your textbook really say "push a byte"**, or is that something you made up?

You can't push *just* a byte in x86, as you say.

Your assembler won't even be able to use the **[`pushl imm8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html)** encoding, because `0x000000FF` doesn't fit in a sign-extended 8-bit integer.  Only values from -128 (0xFFFFFF80) to 127 (0x0000007F) fit in a signed 8-bit integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so pushw $0x08 or pushb $0x08 valid in IA32?

Comment: @amjad: no, `pushb` doesn't exist.  See the last section of my answer, and/or the linked question for which operand-sizes are available.

Comment: @amjad: or you could have just tried it on your desktop: `cat > foo.S` / `pushb $0x8` and run `gcc -c foo.S && objdump -drwC foo.o` to see the error message, or the disassembly if it assembles.  Or do it online: https://godbolt.org/g/iTwiws.  But the compiler-explorer asm-source mode doesn't show the machine code :/