# trying to push "variable" to stack

Tags: windows, variables, assembly, stack, x86-64

I have following code:

```
[bits 64]
%define msg db "%i\n", 0xa, 0
%define var -4
mov r8, rsp
mov [r8+(var)], WORD 0xFFFF
push WORD [r8+(var)] ; not works
; if trying to push DWORD its shows error instruction not supported in 64 bit asm
push DWORD 0xFFFF ; works
call tCtAKBWomJ
msg
tCtAKBWomJ:
call [rbx+3*8]
add rsp, 8
push 0
call [rbx]
```

> call [rbx + x * 8]

is call to asmloader api

x = 0, exit

x = 3, printf

etc.

i want to move value to "variable" and push it to stack.

EDIT:

```
[bits 64]

; const
%define msg db "%i", 0xa, 0

; vars offsets
%define var 8
; vars address
mov r8, rsp

; set var to 0xFFFF
mov DWORD [r8+(var)], 0xFFFF
; push var
push QWORD [r8+(var)]
; push const string msg
call tCtAKBWomJ
msg
tCtAKBWomJ:
; call printf
call [rbx+3*8]
add rsp, 8
; exit
push 0
call [rbx]
```

"variable offset" should be + value, not -.

and i should use

> push QWORD

Comment: You should never need the `bits 64` directive as it doesn't lead to functioning programs.  Instead, select the appropriate flags to create a 64 bit object when runninig the assembler.  That said, there is indeed no `PUSH DWORD` instruction in 64 bit mode.  Try `PUSH QWORD` instead.  But that said, you do not pass arguments to functions on the stack in 64 bit mode normally, so your code may not work correctly even with that.

Comment: thanks, push qword has helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
PUSH DWORD [r8+(var)]
```

use

```
PUSH QWORD [r8+(var)]
```

as all words pushed on the stack are qwords.

Answer (score 2):

NASM syntax `push DWORD 0xFFFF` is a [push](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html) of a dword immediate, sign-extended to qword, when assembled in 64-bit mode.

**IDK why NASM and YASM accept it without warning; I'd argue they shouldn't because it's misleading,** as you discovered.

Only `push strict dword 1` should work, to override the encoding of the immediate (not the operand-size of the instruction).  Note [the `strict` keyword](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.7), which is used for overriding the normal selection of the shortest encoding (and in this case forcing an imm32 even if the number could be encoded in an imm8).  `push dword 1` does *not* inhibit optimization to `push imm8`, it only sets the operand to `dword`.  Except it doesn't, it sets it to qword in 64-bit mode.  Super confusing and arguably broken.

**The only legal operand-sizes for `push` in 64-bit mode are 64 and 16.** 
 [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushe-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-speci).  32-bit `push` is not encodeable in 64-bit mode.

**This applies to pushes with memory and register operands, not just immediates.**  This is why `push dword [mem]` isn't encodeable; in that case NASM treats it as actually requiring a dword memory operand.

---

A QWORD push-immediate can use an 8-bit or 32-bit immediate, both sign extended to 64.  The width of the immediate is separate from the operand-size (the width of the store to memory, and the amount subtracted from RSP).  Again, see that linked question.