# What value is popped in the last line listed below?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, instruction-set

The code below is contained in a FAT16 boot sector at offset 0x3E of the 512 byte sector. At boot time the sector is loaded to memory at location 0:0x7C00. The first three bytes of the sector are:

> EB 3C 90

which translate to the following jump instruction:

```
JMP SHORT 0x3E
```

which jumps to the start of the code listed below.

My question is about the `push` and the `pop` instructions in the last two lines listed below.
The `push` pushes the byte 0x54 to location 0x7BFF. The `pop` instruction pops the bytes located at 0x7C00 & 0x7BFF into the `ES` register. So `ES = 0xEB54`. But isn't that a very unusual thing to do? **It pops a byte that was never even pushed**. Furthermore, the value in `ES` will eventually be used for a specific purpose later on in the boot sector code.

MY QUESTION: What value is popped into `ES` in the last line below?

```
xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0x7c00
mov bp,sp
cld
sti
mov [bp+0x24],dl
mov al,[bp+0x10]
mul word [bp+0x16]
add ax,[bp+0xe]
adc dl,dh
add ax,[bp+0x1c]
adc dx,[bp+0x1e]
push byte +0x54
pop es
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite the naming, `push byte +0x54` actually pushes a word, so the value in `es` at the end is simply `0x0054`.  x86 has no instruction to literally push just a single byte.

You didn't say what assembler you're using, but the `byte` probably tells the assembler to choose the `push imm8` encoding (opcode `6a`), with an 8-bit immediate which is sign-extended to a 16-bit word, instead of `push imm16` (opcode `68`).  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push

Comment: Sane assemblers will already pick the smallest encoding for an instruction, so for a numeric literal (not something to be filled in by the linker) it's completely pointless (and confusing for some readers) to write `push byte`.  In NASM, you'd write `push strict byte` or `strict word` to force the immediate encoding (and also operand-size), but there's almost never a reason to do that, except maybe to force a wider encoding for self-modifying code.  But never a byte encoding, unless maybe `nasm -O0` doesn't bother to find the smallest encoding otherwise and you want to disable optimization.

Comment: If you did want an 8-bit symbol relocation for a push dword imm8, I'm not sure if there's a way to tell NASM about it if dword isn't already the default operand-size.  e.g. `push dword strict byte symname` is just push dword imm32, treating it like "strict dword". https://godbolt.org/z/E6oe11.  Anyway, related Q&A: [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993) has more about the available operand-sizes in general.

Comment: Oh, I bet it's disassembler output.  This is exactly the syntax that `ndisasm` produces, with the redundant `byte` and `+`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the answer.   Bill S.