# Unnecessary pushing of registers to the stack when others with the same value exist, why?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm

I'm trying to learn socket programming with assembly and I'm told to write this code:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    push    byte 6
    push    byte 1
    push    byte 2
    mov     ecx, esp
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 102
    int     80h
 
    ;confusing part
    mov     edi, eax ;why is this (and pushing it) necessary?
    push    dword 0x00000000
    push    word 0x2923
    push    word 2
    mov     ecx, esp
    push    byte 16
    push    ecx      
    push    edi      ;why not push eax directly? Doesn't sys_socketcall put the file descriptor back into eax?
    mov     ecx, esp 
    mov     ebx, 2
    mov     eax, 102
    int     80h
```

I added comments to the parts I don't understand. The full code with the irrelevant parts can be found [here](https://asmtutor.com/#lesson30).

Why do they move a register's value to another? Couldn't they just push the original one?

Comment: You can push `eax` directly but you need to move the file descriptor out of `eax` or you'll lose it after the `int 80h`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Doesn't sys_socketcall put the file descriptor into `eax`? Or is that the case only when `ebx` is 1?

Comment: I'd expect `socketcall` to behave like the functions it calls. So I'd expect only the "socket" call (1) to return a file descriptor, the other one should return the error code or similar. Check the manual, I've never used `socketcall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov edi,eax` is one way to keep the `fd` available for use *after* the second `int 80h`.  **If you've decided you're going to keep the socket `fd` in EDI from now on, as its permanent home, it makes sense to `push edi`**.  But yes, `push eax` would work because at this point there's still a copy of it in EAX.

It seems rather pointless in the "lesson 30" where they first introduce this; they just exit right away.  But if you look at later "lessons" they build on this code, using it unchanged and adding more system calls after (like `listen`, which also uses `push edi`).  In later code, you still want to push the `fd` from `socket()`, not the return value from `bind()`.

---

The code is a bit hacky, e.g. not removing the structs they keep pushing, so if you did this in a loop you'd run out of stack space eventually.  Normally you'd `add esp, whatever` to undo the pushes after a system call.

Or use `mov` stores to the stack to replace the existing struct of args with the new one.  If the file-descriptor is in the same place, you could just leave it there.  (Or in the current code, `push dword [esp+24]` or something in the next block of code, but keeping the fd in a register makes a lot more sense if you're going to store it again.)

It's also weird to write something like `push byte 1`.  That still adjusts ESP by 4 and stores `0x00000001`, unlike `push word 2` which only adjusts ESP by 2 and stores `0x0002`.  ([How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif))

(x86 only supports word and dword operand-size for push, but supports imm8 and full-width immediates.  If you wanted to force a 1-byte immediate, the syntax is `push strict byte 1`, but NASM already does that because optimization is enabled by default in NASM for at least a decade.)

---

BTW, since Linux 4.3, there are separate system-call numbers for i386 for every system call in the sockets API, like `bind` and `listen`, so you don't need to push structs on the stack and call the generic `socketcall` entry point.  [The man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketcall.2.html) says x86-64 and ARM don't have a `socketcall` system call at all, always just separate syscall entry points for each system call.