# "error: operation size not specified" on push operation. Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm, instruction-set

I'm trying to make a simple x86 program that reverses a string, in this case: "ciao".

```
section .data
        msg db "ciao"
        len equ $ - msg

section .text
global _start
_start:
        lea eax, [msg]
        mov ebx, len
        add eax, ebx-1
reverseloop:
        push [eax]
        sub eax, 1
        cmp eax, [msg]
        jl reverseloop
```

When I try to assemble it, I get the error:

> main.asm:14: error: operation size not specified

So, I tried to specify the size, by modifying line 14 to:

```
push byte [eax]
```

And now I get the error:

> main.asm:14: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

I don't really understand what is the problem here.
The command I use to compile is:

> nasm -f elf32 main.asm -o main.o

Comment: In 32-bit modes `push` with a memory operand only supports pushing a word or a dword. You can't push a byte. So you could only do `push word [eax]` or `push dword [eax]` but you can't do `push byte [eax]` . See an Instruction Set Architecture document like: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> push [eax]
> ```

NASM does not know the size of the memory operand that you would like to push. You need to specify it as `push dword [eax]`.
It is not an option to use `push byte [eax]` because the stack operations don't do single bytes.

> ```
> add eax, ebx-1
> ```

This is your next error! The source operand `ebx-1` is invalid.
You could first decrement EBX and then add that to EAX, but as I will show below you don't need this decrement.

> ```
> cmp eax, [msg]
> jl reverseloop
> ```

This is not doing what you want either. The `cmp` compares EAX to a dword from memory, but you want this to be a comparison between addresses. Use `cmp eax, msg`.
And in order to continu the loop for all characters of the string, you need to conditionally jump for as long as the address in EAX is **GreaterOrEqual** *msg*.

```
  mov   eax, msg
  add   eax, len
reverseloop:
  dec   eax
  movzx ebx, byte [eax]
  push  ebx
  cmp   eax, msg
  ja    reverseloop
```

Now I don't see how this code will reverse anything. The characters land on the stack in the same order as they were in the memory (interspersed with some zero bytes of course).

```
  mov   eax, msg
  mov   ecx, len
reverseloop1:
  movzx ebx, byte [eax]
  push  ebx
  inc   eax
  dec   ecx
  jnz   reverseloop1

  mov   eax, msg
  mov   ecx, len
reverseloop2:
  pop   ebx
  mov   [eax], bl
  inc   eax
  dec   ecx
  jnz   reverseloop2
```

Solutions that don't use the stack exist and generally would be better.

Comment: `lea eax, [eax+ebx-1]` is a valid instruction that can do what they were trying to.  Oh, but `ebx` was set with `mov ebx, len` so that's silly, just `mov eax, msg+len-1` or transform like you did.

Comment: For `push`, it's interesting that NASM [will default to DWORD operand-size for immediates like `push 123`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif), but requires disambiguation of `word` vs `dword` for memory operands like `push [eax]`.  It's probably just as rare that you'd ever want `push word [mem]` as `push word immediate`, but that's the design choice NASM made.  But probably even more important to be explicit about memory operand sizes for push and pop; bugs with that might be less obvious.