# How to move the zero flag into a register in x86-64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, eflags

I want to move the zero flag set as the result of a comparison, e.g. "cmp rax,rbx", into a register.  I know I can use one of PUSHF/PUSHFD/PUSHFQ to push the flags onto the stack, but now I want to move just the zero flag from the stack to a register.

According to https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pushf:pushfd:pushfq, it "Decrements the stack pointer by 4 (if the current operand-size attribute is 32) and pushes the entire contents of the EFLAGS register onto the stack."  But that doesn't tell me the order they are pushed and how to access the zero flag.

According to the Intel Software Developers Manual (June 2023), section 7.3.13.2, the zero flag is #6 from the base at zero. (Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)). So from that I would guess that `mov al,[rsp+6]` would do it.  But I need to be sure because they are all just booleans -- I may grab the wrong boolean.

I'm in 64-bit mode, so I would be addressing the RFLAGS register.  Section 7.3.1.4 of the manual says, "PUSHF and POPF behave the same in 64-bit mode as in non-64-bit mode. PUSHFD always pushes 64-bit RFLAGS onto the stack (with the RF and VM flags read as clear). POPFD always pops a 64-bit value from the top of the stack and loads the lower 32 bits into RFLAGS. It then zero extends the upper bits of RFLAGS."

Finally, what's the difference between PUSHFD and PUSHFQ?  Double word and quadword, but which should I use in 64-bit mode?

Comment: There are really only two options: 16-bit pushf (which you shouldn't use except in 16-bit code), and not-16-bit pushf, with size depending on the mode you're in (32-bit or 64-bit). Would you mind using `setz` instead though? `pushf` is fairly expensive.

Comment: Setz sounds like it would do the trick.  16-bit mode, as you say, is not practical.

Comment: What about `lahf`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: That would be useful in 16-bit code that might run on a pre-386.  But unless there are some CPUs where it's a lot faster than `setz ah` (doubtful), it's worse because it needs some post-processing to isolate ZF.  (You could test-and-branch on it just as efficiently, but if you wanted that you could have used `jz` in the first place.  Unless you're saving this ZF condition for later branching after something else that uses FLAGS, maybe.)  Also, it writes a high-8 partial register, which is even worse than `setcc` which can at least be used on a low-8 register.

Comment: It's not a big concern today but there were a couple of x64 processors that didn't support `lahf` in 64-bit mode

Comment: @harold: BTW, on Intel, `pushf` isn't super slow, only 3 uops. (https://uops.info/table.html).  It's slower on Zen, though, 9 to 11 uops with 4c throughput.  On Intel it's `popf` that's really slow, since it might have to change IF or other machine-state stuff.  `pushf/pop` Store/reload is still clearly worse the `setcc` even if it's followed with a `movzx` that can't benefit from mov-elimination, except in the worst case where a false dependency from `setcc` writing a partial register is even worse than a push/pop store-forwarding latency and extra uops.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `pushf` for this.  As has already been mentioned in comments, the best way to materialize ZF into a register is the conditional set instruction `setz`.  This is exactly what it's for.  `setcc reg8` sets an 8-bit register to 0 or 1 according to whether the condition code `cc` is false or true.

The fact that it sets an 8-bit partial register, and leaves the other 56 bits of the 64-bit register unchanged, is awkward.  It's rarely useful behavior, and is actually bad for performance because it can introduce a read dependency on the previous 64-bit register value.  To mitigate this, you can zero the 64-bit register first.  For instance:

```
xor ecx, ecx
cmp rax, rbx
setz cl
```

Note that `xor ecx, ecx` actually zeros all of `rcx`, and is more efficient than the obvious `xor rcx, rcx`; see [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) and [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  And make sure the `xor` goes before the `cmp`, not after, since `xor` updates the flags.

---

The `pushf` family is not a good choice here; it is a fairly slow instruction in itself (about 5-10 clock cycles latency), involves memory access, and then requires more work to manipulate the bits of the result.  `setz` on the other hand is typically just one clock cycle.  If for some reason you couldn't use `setz`, then your next best option would be a conditional jump:

```
    xor ecx, ecx
    cmp rax, rbx
    jnz onward
    mov ecx, 1
onward:
    ;; more code
```

---

But as far as your actual questions about `pushf`.

As far as "order", `pushfq` in 64-bit mode pushes the entire RFLAGS register as a single 64-bit value.  The layout of RFLAGS is found in the Intel manuals and also in the Wikipedia page you already linked.  The bit numbers start with 0 as the least significant bit.  So ZF is **bit** 6, and a working but inefficient way to materialize ZF would be

```
pushfq
pop rax
shr eax, 6
and eax, 1
```

Your proposed `mov al, [rsp+6]` would load `al` with **byte** 6, i.e. bits 48-55.  All bits above 32 are reserved and will probably be 0, so this will just give you 0 in `al`.  Again, the flags are the individual bits of a single 64-bit quadword; they are not pushed as 64 separate bytes.

---

`pushfd` and `pushfq` are the same opcode; the question of whether to push 32 or 64 bits is determined by the current CPU mode.  If you have correctly told your assembler that you are writing code for 64-bit mode (e.g. with `bits 64` in nasm) then it will refuse to assemble `pushfd`.

nasm will actually treat the `pushf` mnemonic in 64-bit mode as `pushfq` since that is normally what you want.  It is however possible to execute a 16-bit flag push in 64-bit mode with an operand size override byte; Intel's manuals call this `pushf` but nasm would require you to write it as `pushfw`.  This is not useful, though, since it misaligns the stack.  In 64-bit mode,  you always want to push and pop full 64-bit (8-byte) units, except in very unusual situations.

Comment: Some assemblers do assemble `pushf` as `pushfw`, like I think JWASM (MASM compatible) might do that, so you need to write `pushfq`.  But that's weird, and fortunately NASM defaults the `pushf` operand-size the same way it defaults `push 123`, to be the same width as the current mode, not using any width-changing prefixes.  [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning the [APX extension](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) planned for future CPUs, which will introduce `setcc.zu rax` (zu = Zero Upper, encoded with a 4-byte EVEX prefix unfortunately, not just a 2-byte REX2.  IDK why it's more useful to have a shorter encoding of the bad old form.)  Or perhaps some assemblers will want you to write it as `setz rax`, with the operand-size implying that it's the APX encoding.  NASM 2.16 doesn't support it yet, and no CPUs do yet.

Answer (score 1):

This MASM example extracts the [ZF (bit #6)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) from the RFLAGS register using the very inefficient `PUSHFQ/POP` method and stores it in the `rcx` register. As noted in the comments below, there are much more efficient alternatives.

```
option casemap:none

.code

main proc
    mov rax,0               ; Init to 0
    mov rbx,0               ; Init to 0
    cmp rax,rbx             ; Comparison equal, sets ZF=1
    pushfq                  ; Push RFLAGS onto the stack
    pop rcx                 ; Load the RFLAGS from the stack into rcx
    shr rcx, 6              ; Shift right by 6, so the ZF is now the LSB of rcx
    and rcx, 1              ; Zero all other bits, except the LSB
                            ; rcx contains the ZF moved from the stack to a register
    ret
main endp

end
```

Here's a brief overview of the first 16-bit flags register:

[image: flags]

Comment: A good answer to this question should at least mention `setz cl`, not just this inefficient way the OP's working on.  Preferably `xor ecx,ecx` / `cmp rax, rbx` / `setz cl`, but you can if necessary `movzx edx, cl` or something after the cmp, if it was too inconvenient to zero a register before the FLAGS-setting.  (Prefer separate registers for so mov-elimination can work, not `movzx ecx, cl`). Anyway, `pushf` / `pop` is a bad way to get a register set to a FLAGS value; `setcc` is the standard way to materialize a FLAGS condition into an integer reg.

Comment: For those flag bits that are not accessible via [SETcc](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc), the `pushfq/pop` method would be a valid solution.

Comment: That's true; the only "condition code" flag where that applies is AF; there's on `cc` that reads it for `jcc` / `setcc` / `cmovcc`.  But it's accessible via `lahf`.  `pushf` / `pop` is only useful for multiple condition codes at once, or for stuff like IF, TF, DF, etc.