# Does setcc zero-extend the register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

A setcc instruction writes to the low byte of a register.  If I write, e.g., "setnl cl" will ecx/rcx be zero-extended?

EDIT:  after the comments made below, I see that setcc does not zero-extend the register.

Comment: No, just like always, writing a byte register doesn't affect other bytes of the full register.  Basically a duplicate of [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178).  You could easily have tried it yourself by making the upper bytes non-zero.  (This bad design of `setcc` is why APX is planning to introduce a zero-upper form that *will* allow `setnl rcx`)

Comment: Also, you just asked [How to move the zero flag into a register in x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77062912) a couple weeks ago, where Nate's answer clearly stated **it sets an 8-bit partial register, and leaves the other 56 bits of the 64-bit register unchanged**

Comment: Then that answers it.  It does not zero-extend.  I missed that in Nate's answer.  Thank you for taking the time to comment on this question.