# Converting 64bit asm to 32bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm working on a project which involves loading a dll into an application that has 64bit and 32bit versions. I do not have access to the source code for this app, I am injecting instruction into a codecave to make use of the imported LoadLibrary, and the dll that gets loaded will hook function calls.

For the 64bit version, I do the following:

```
JMP codecave (this is at entry, replaces func that I call in codecave lbl to return)
```

In codecave:

```
unicode  u"example.dll"

PUSH     EAX
MOV      RCX, [dllstr] (address of unicode string for name of dll)
CALL     qword ptr [loadlibraryw] (address of LoadLibraryW)
POP      EAX
JMP      entryfunc (return to original code)
```

This works fine!

---

In the 32bit version of the app, LoadLibraryA is used instead, so my string is no longer unicode:

```
ds       "example.dll"
```

The JMP to codecave uses the same entry point with replacing the func, and the codecave location is similar, at the end of executable .text section.

The thing I'm not sure about is which registers to work with in 32bit. From the function signature it seems LoadLibraryA is still using EAX for storage so I assume I still need to push/pop EAX.

I am not certain on where to move the string to, from examples I've seen it seems I should use PUSH without register like:

```
PUSH     EAX
PUSH     dllstr
CALL     dword ptr [loadlibrarya]
POP      EAX
JMP      entryfunc
```

But this causes the app to crash. I suspect because I'm altering the stack here, but I need clarification on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't LoadLibraryW an option for you? The only Win32 environments I'm not sure it will be on are prior to Windows 2000 (and even then, I think it was on Win95/98/ME but behaved slightly differently, maybe internally converting to ANSI code pages) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/march/windows-2000-loader-what-goes-on-inside-windows-2000-solving-the-mysteries-of-the-loader

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't obvious: I don't have access to the code of the app, I am injecting asm to load a dll making use of the imported LoadLibrary in the app.

LoadLibraryW is in the imports of the 64bit version, the 32bit version is older and imports LoadLibraryA instead. It's not really relevant which I use because the only difference is the type of string that accept as argument, which is easy enough to change.

Comment: `PUSH     EAX` isn't a valid 64-bit instruction.  (only 16 or 64-bit operand-size for `push`/`pop`).   `CALL  qword ptr [loadlibrarya]` isn't a valid 32-bit instruction; only 32-bit `dword ptr` for an ordinary call.  (You don't want a far call, and that would be a 48-bit operand, not qword either).  So IDK what instructions you actually injected, but it's not these.

Comment: Another significant difference between 32 and 64-bit is that 64-bit use relative addressing for addressing modes like `[loadlibraryw]`, and has RIP-relative LEA for getting a pointer into a register.  But you're not using `lea rcx, [unicode]`, you're loading an absolute address from some static storage you didn't show, presumably `dllstr: dq unicode`.  (MASM uses RIP-relative by default for `[foo]`, NASM and GAS don't; I don't know what assembler you're actually using for these.) Anyway, those addressing modes in 32-bit code need correct *absolute* addresses, not just relative, in machine code

Comment: Also, EAX isn't the only call-clobbered register.  In 32-bit code, there's also EDX and ECX.  In Windows x64, there are more, including R8-R11.  And they're 64-bit like RAX, RDX, and RCX.  Also, Windows x64 has shadow space, 32 bytes above the return address, which you didn't reserve so `call [loadlibraryw]` will step on the caller's stack space.  If anything, I'd expect the 64-bit code to be the one that's broken.

Comment: Yes I mistakenly put `qword` instead of `dword` for the 32bit one. But the 64bit one is what I did, and it did work, so... I am using ghidra for this and these are instructions it accepts.

Comment: @iegrm: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  `push eax` is literally not encodeable in 64-bit mode, see [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993) .  If you're using a buggy assembler, we might need to see the machine code as well.  Except that's for the one you say does work.

Comment: I don't know what syntax Ghidra's assembler uses; if it's NASM-like, you'd want `push label_on_string` to push the address as an immediate.  Or `push dword [some_pointer]` if for some reason you want to load the address from a pointer instead of using it as an immediate.  You're doing that in your 64-bit code but I don't know why; RIP-relative LEA should work.

Comment: You say it faults, but you haven't said how or where.  Use a debugger to find out.